# MySQL Cursor not working with Date variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, database-cursor

I have a mysql cursor that is not returning any records when comparing a date variable to a date column in the table. All of this is taking place inside a stored procedure. Hence:

```
    DECLARE StartDateInterval Date DEFAULT '1997-11-01';

    DECLARE EndDateInterval Date DEFAULT '1997-12-31';

    DECLARE End_Period Date DEFAULT '1997-12-31'; 

    DECLARE prev_period_tournie_rating CURSOR FOR select PID, Rating, RD from rating where Rating_Date = End_Period;

    SET End_Period = (StartDateInterval - interval 1 day);

    OPEN prev_period_tournie_rating;

        firstloop: LOOP
            FETCH prev_period_tournie_rating INTO vPID, PrevRat, PrevRD;
            IF done = 1 THEN LEAVE firstloop;  END IF;
            SET decayedRD  = ROUND(`newRD`(PrevRD));
            INSERT into rating (PID, Rating, RD, Rating_Date, Rating_Type) VALUES (vPID, PrevRat, decayedRD, EndDateInterval, 2);
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE prev_period_tournie_rating;
```

There is more code in the Stored Procedure that I have deleted. After the DECLARE statements, all of the above takes place inside a WHILE . . .END WHILE that iterates through 2 month intervals from 1997 to the present, hence the need for End_Period to be a variable and not coded to a single date.

When I remove the where condition the Cursor retrieves records from the rating table.

I do not pass End_Period as a paramater in the cursor DECLARE statement. It appears that some mysql dialects allow/require this and some don't. Even though I have tried to set my dialect to MariaDB (which does allow parameters, I get an error if I add End_Period as a parameter.

Rating_Date is a date column in the table rating, using the standard mysql format (YYYY-MM-DD).

Any help on solving this would be appreciated. This is my first attempt at using a Stored Procedure and it is proving to be a challenge!

Comment: MariaDB is more a fork than a dialect. If that's what you're actually using, I'd suggest you reflect it in question tags.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=940b01be6240b86c0d8260b0658791d9).